# How to make a new Line every 8th input

Tags: java

My code requires me to create an array (from user input), display it backwards, and find the sum of each number. So far I have been able to accomplish all requirements. However, if the array is more than 8 numbers, then when it is displayed the program must create a new line every 8th number. I'm having difficulty accomplishing this goal. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length;
        double sumArray = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many elements in the array? ");
        length = input.nextInt();

        }

        for(int j = currentArray.length-1; j >= 0; j-- )
        {
            System.out.printf("%.3f \t", currentArray[j]);

            if(currentArray.length - 8 == j) // here is where I'm having the problem
            {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }


        input.close();
    }

}
```

What should go inside of the if statement in order to create a new line each time 8 inputs are displayed?

This is what output should look like :

> How many elements in the array? 20
>
> Please enter the next value 1
>
> Please enter the next value 2
>
> Please enter the next value 3
>
> Please enter the next value 4
>
> Please enter the next value 5
>
> Please enter the next value 6
>
> Please enter the next value 7
>
> Please enter the next value 8
>
> Please enter the next value 9
>
> Please enter the next value 10
>
> Please enter the next value 11
>
> Please enter the next value 12
>
> Please enter the next value 13
>
> Please enter the next value 14
>
> Please enter the next value 15
>
> Please enter the next value 16
>
> Please enter the next value 17
>
> Please enter the next value 18
>
> Please enter the next value 19
>
> Please enter the next value 20
>
> 20.000    19.000  18.000  17.000  16.000  15.000  14.000  13.000
>   12.000    11.000  10.000  9.000   8.000   7.000   6.000   5.000
>   4.000     3.000   2.000   1.000
>
> The Sum of the array's elements is : 210.000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer isn't working correctly because you're backing up through the list from the end back to the beginning, but the mod operator causes line breaks as if you were moving from the beginning to the end.  However, the idea of using the modulo operator is definitely correct.  Do this in your if statement:

```
if((length - j) % 8 == 0) {
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to do something every *n* times, you want to use [modulo division](https://javaranch.com/drive/modulo.html): `%`.

Change this

```java
if(currentArray.length - 8 == j) // here is where I'm having the problem
{
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

To this

```java
if (j % 8 == 0) // here is where I'm having the problem
{
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: That does not cause the program to create a new line.

Comment: @StaticBeagle it really should be just `j % 8` ... <facepalm>. Edited to fix.

Comment: @alttag if you input 17 numbers, this code will cause a new line to be created after one input at 17-1 = 16 and 16 %8 ==0 . I need it to create a new line after 8 inputs

Comment: It's still happening every eight lines, right? If it's an off-by-one error, change `j % 8` to `(j+1) % 8`.